# PHP adds \ to JSON

Tags: php, get, httprequest, json

My shared web hosting adds \ to JSON. I use ExtJS and it normally sends this data

```
[{"property":"id","direction":"ASC"}]
```

Howere PHP receives or chages it as `[{\"property\":\"id\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]`

Thus I cannot use `json_decode($_REQUEST['sort'])`

I think this is because they wanted to prevent SQL injection but now they break my application. What I have to do?

Edit:

```
$sort = json_decode($_GET['sort']);
print_r($_GET); // [sort] => [{\"property\":\"id\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]
print_r($sort); //
```

Comment: maybe this function can help you?
http://am.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if you vHost has [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.what.php) enabled.

Someone over [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.whynot.php) proposed this to get the unchanged values:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

    function strip_array($var) {

        return ( is_array($var)
               ? array_map("strip_array", $var)
               : stripslashes($var)
               );
    }

    $_POST = strip_array($_POST);
    $_SESSION = strip_array($_SESSION);
    $_GET = strip_array($_GET);

}
```